# Unable to use back button property in Popup screen in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-simulator

In my application , am using popup screen, that implements FieldChangeListener.I used close() method for back button. but its not working.

Can some give sample code without using `KeyListener`,`TrackwheelListener` ?

Answer (score 2):

if u want to close the popup screen on back button try this:

```
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().
popScreen(UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen());
```